# Why this code prints contents of an irrelevant char array?

Tags: c, algorithm

I was working on exercises in K&R's The C Programming Language Book. In the Exercise 2-4, I was writing an experimental code:

```
void printstr(char s[])
{
   int i=0;
   while(s[i] != '\0')
   {
      printf("%c", s[i++]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   char sa[] = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd'};
   char sb[] = {'a'};
//   squeeze(sa, sb);
   printstr(sb);
   return 0;
}
```

You would expect this code prints a single "a" and then quits, right? However the output is:

```
$ gcc exercise_2-4.c
$ ./a.out
aababced
```

But if I disable definition of "sa" array by commenting it out, prints as it's expected:

```
gcc exercise_2-4.c
./a.out
a
```

I'm somehow aware of this is not happening insanely, it's tied to a reason but I really wondered about it.

Comment: Where do you think the `'\0'` character is in the array you've passed to the function? `char sb[] = "a";` would add one at the end, but if you construct the array with character literals it will not. You'd need to add it yourself.

Comment: You need either `char sb[] = {'a', '\0'};` or `char sb[] = "a";` and similar for `sa`.

Comment: Somehow I always thought it's added by automatically to end of char arrays, now I figured out. Thanks! @RetiredNinja

Comment: This is an excellent demonstration of undefined behaviour. Your loop does not terminate before it overflows the end of the array because it does not encounter the '\0' it is expecting. Once you start indexing beyond the end of the array *anything could happen*.

Comment: @Rodney, now I completely understand I must finish my char arrays with additional '\0' character, but why is it jumping to contents of "sa" array? And it's not randomly happening, it's always same when I run the program again and again. Also, why is that "anything" is not happening after the program reads sa's contents but not sb's?

Comment: Because there is no terminator. Eventually it will probably find one by accident. Incorrect code behaves mysteriously, and questioning it leads you nowhere.

Comment: "Anything" does not mean "random behaviour". It just means "anything", which might alsways be the same thing, always a diffenent thing, even always correct.

Comment: @brm1911 Because the compiler decided to put `sa` directly after `sb` in memory so you just ran off the end of one array into the next one. Then for whatever reason there were some zeros in memory after that and it stopped. This sort of thing is completely unpredictable (the compiler could have put those arrays in a different order, for example). When you index outside the array, you *might* end up in another array, or you *might* end up accessing memory that isn't accessible and cause a page fault, or something else might happen. The standard simply says the result is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you access arrays outside bounds, you invoke undefined behaviour (**UB**). Your program behaviour cannot be determined from the C language point of view.

You need to null terminate it yourself:

```
   char sa[] = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', 0};
   char sb[] = {'a', 0};
```

or initialize using ***string literals***

```
   char sa[] = "ababced";
   char sb[] = "a";
```